# Google drive API - orderBy very slow

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

**[(Note: This is a self-answering question)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)**

I noticed `orderBy` `folder,title` is very slow, what should I do ?

```
$ time curl 'https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?maxResults=10&orderBy=folder%2Ctitle&q=%27root%27%20in%20parents%20and%20trashed%3Dfalse&key=XXX' --compressed -H 'Authorization: Bearer XXX' -H 'X-Origin: https://explorer.apis.google.com'  -H 'If-None-Match: "XXX"'
```

It requires almost ~11 seconds to complete:

```
real    0m11.356s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.016s
```

You can [test in API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#try-it). The query is:

- maxResults: 10
- ordeBy: folder,title
- q: 'root' in parents and trashed=false

Comment: @DaImTo This is obviously google API v2 problem, since change the orderBy from `folder,title` to `title,folder` when q is empty will cut down the time from 12 to 1 second.

Comment: If you have some stats you may want to post this on the issue forum https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191650%2B.   I suspect this is going to be hard to prove as it could just be an issue with your connection, or the amount of data or a number of other factors. Note: I don't think there is any development being done on v2 anymore.  So i don't think there is really anything you can do about it.

Comment: @DaImTo I filed a bug report at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69785597

Comment: I feel very disappointed to self-answering to help the community(It did solved my problem) while what I get is downvote. Keep in mind accept self-answering answer will not earn any reputation.

Answer (score -2):

**[(Note: I'm self-answering my question)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)**

[API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list#try-it) is working, consider to migrate from v2 if possible. It will cut down to <1 second (the field `title` in v2 is called `name` in v3, and `maxResults` in v2 is called `pageSize` in v3):

```
$ time curl 'https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?orderBy=folder%2Cname&pageSize=10&q=%27root%27%20in%20parents%20and%20trashed%3Dfalse&key=XXX' --compressed  -H 'Authorization: Bearer XXX' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'X-Origin: https://explorer.apis.google.com'
...
real    0m0.674s
user    0m0.024s
sys     0m0.004s
```

In v3, you also need specify `fields`, e.g. (click "Show standard parameters" to expand the field form in "Try-it API explorer"):

```
files(kind,id,name,size,mimeType,thumbnailLink)
```

More: [Migrate to Google Drive API v3 from Google Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration)

Comment: @DaImTo This suggest migrate to v3 to solve the problem. Did you ever try the request before downvote ?

Comment: The original question is about Google Drive v2 suggesting v3, isn't going to solve the problem with v2.   IMO this doesn't really answer the question.   Maybe add it as a coment on the original question

Comment: @UrbanEsc I'm self-answering my question. I found the answer before I created this question, since no solution yet in the internet.

Comment: @DaImTo  Migrate to v3 to solve v2 problem is a valid solution even though not the best, but as a developer you have no choice to wait for Google to fix it before publish my app, not to say they may never bother to fix old API. I have a hard time in Youtube API and I knew their styles.

Comment: I hope you guy understood, 11 seconds delay is unacceptable in user perspective. I must fix it, but should I have to wait forever from Google ? This answer is a workaround to remind you v3 is working, consider to migrate if possible.